# Java IMAP subject decoding

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using javamail. If the email is cyrrilic, the subject is "Текст =?UTF-8?B?INCv0L3QtNC10LrRgS7QlNC10L3RjNCz0LDRhQ==?="
How to decode it?
I've tried MimeUtility, but no result

Comment: Please, show us what you've tryed so far... and be more specific on what you aim to.

Answer (score 0):

If the message is properly formatted, Message.getSubject will decode the Subject text for you.  Your example looks like it has some non-ASCII text before the "=?UTF-8" part.  If it does, that indicates that the message was not properly encoded to begin with.

What mailer was used to send the message you're trying to read?

What result do you expect if the message is properly decoded?

Comment: "Message.getSubject will decode the Subject text for you". It doesn't decode it.
I read messages from imap3.

Comment: Details, please.  Show the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) when you access this message from your mail server.